# Есть функция с getSelection. Не получается реализовать такой алгоритм: по окончанию выделения нужно создать button рядом с выделенным словом

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```
function getRangeObject(win) {
  win = win || window;
   if (win.getSelection) { 
    try{    
        return win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } catch (e) { /*If no text is selected an exception might be thrown*/ }
  } else if (win.document.selection) { // IE8   
    var range = win.document.selection.createRange(); //Microsoft TextRange Object
    return fixIERangeObject(range, win);
  }
  return null;
}
function test() {
      var range = getRangeObject();
      if (range) {
        alert(range);
      } else {
        alert('Сначала выделите текст');
      }
    }
```

Эту функцию можно вызвать с помощью баттона на онклик:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test();" />
```

Вопрос: как сделать,что бы алерт выскакивал не по **баттону**,а при **окончании выделения**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/7145756

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то , что нужно!)

Comment: CTACO23, пожалуйста)